# Google cloud messaging notification

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

There is an app with news from the site RSS parser. How to make push notification about a new post in the application. And when I click on the notification, the application opens with the last post from the site

Comment: Are you asking how to generate a test push notification or receive a push notification?

Comment: @BrianRisk if on the rss feed new post, in the application I get notification about it

Comment: You may want to start with [setting up a GCM Client App on Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) then proceed with this [tutorial](https://jmsliu.com/3009/add-push-notification-in-android-rss-reader-using-google-cloud-messaging.html) which demonstrates how to add the push notification in the Android RSS Reader app with Google Cloud Messaging. This [article](https://dzone.com/articles/building-rss-reader-android) might also help.